# Terraform Error: Error: Failed to load plugin schemas while running Terraform for azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am running terraform plan through Azure pipelines for windows virtual machine. We had previously created the VM and all related resources in terrform 0.12 and AzureRM 2.20. I have upgraded the code to 1.5.6. When running the terrform init with upgrade option, the initialization is a success, but, the plan fails. The code basically uses the azure keyvault to store a customer managed key and uses that for the managed disk for the windows virtual machine. We are trying to upgrade terraform provider versions to use key rotation. The random module is used to generate VM password.

This is how my new provider block looks

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.5.6"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.50.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {} #Backend variables are initialized through the secret and variable folders
}
```

```
provider "azurerm" {
  # Whilst the `version` attribute is optional, we recommend pinning to a given version of the Provider
  #version         = "~> 3.50.0"
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id

  features {}
}
```

This is the precise error message

```
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│ 
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain
│ provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm" to obtain schema: unavailable provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm"..
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│ 
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain
│ provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm" to obtain schema: unavailable provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm"..
╵
╷
│ Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│ 
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: 2 problems:
│ 
│ - Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm" to obtain schema: unavailable provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm".
│ - Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider
│ registry.terraform.io/-/random: failed to instantiate provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/random" to obtain schema: unavailable provider
│ "registry.terraform.io/-/random"..
```

When I dug deeper into the terraform trace, I can see the following error messages:

```
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_key_vault_key.this
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windows_vms
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_network_interface.windows_nics
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.this
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] terraform.contextPlugins: Initializing provider "terraform.io/builtin/terraform" to read its schema
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [ERROR] AttachSchemaTransformer: No provider config schema available for provider["terraform.io/builtin/terraform"]
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_backup_protected_vm.this
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_key_vault_secret.this
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to data.terraform_remote_state.loadbalancer
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to data.terraform_remote_state.applicationsecuritygroup
2023-09-06T19:57:41.714Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching provider config schema to provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"]
```

Another Spot of error:

```
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.this (expand)
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to data.azurerm_backup_policy_vm.this (expand)
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to data.terraform_remote_state.storage (expand)
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [ERROR] AttachSchemaTransformer: No provider config schema available for provider["terraform.io/builtin/terraform"]
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_key_vault_key.this (expand)
2023-09-06T19:57:42.582Z [TRACE] AttachSchemaTransformer: attaching resource schema to azurerm_disk_encryption_set.this (expand)
```

I have verified that the downloaded plugins have execute privileges after terraform init.

The following block shows a listing of .terraform directory:

```
./.terraform:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps    5 Sep  6 19:46 environment
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 providers
-rw-r--r-- 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 1398 Sep  6 19:46 terraform.tfstate

./.terraform/providers:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 registry.terraform.io

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 hashicorp

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 azurerm
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 random

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 3.50.0

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.50.0:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 linux_amd64

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.50.0/linux_amd64:
total 187464
drwxr-xr-x 2 AzDevOps AzDevOps      4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps      4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 191954944 Sep  6 19:46 terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.50.0_x5

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 3.5.1

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random/3.5.1:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 AzDevOps AzDevOps 4096 Sep  6 19:46 linux_amd64

./.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random/3.5.1/linux_amd64:
total 12904
drwxr-xr-x 2 AzDevOps AzDevOps     4096 Sep  6 19:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 AzDevOps AzDevOps     4096 Sep  6 19:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 AzDevOps AzDevOps 13205504 Sep  6 19:46 terraform-provider-random_v3.5.1_x5
```

Answer (score 0):

When ‘Failed to load plugin schemas’ shows up, it means that Terraform failed to locate provider schemas for azurerm and random providers.  This can occur when providers have not been installed or when the providers are installed with the wrong directory path.

You have to rectify this mistake by properly installing and configuring the azurerm and random providers.  You can do this by running the following command:

##### `terraform init:`

Finally, if the provider schemas have not been found by Terraform, you may give direct instructions to the provider plugins.  To achieve this, you should set the **TF_PLUGIN_CACHE** environment variable to point to the directory containing the plugin providers.

For example, if the provider plugins are installed in the **/usr/local/share/terraform/plugins** directory, you would set the **TF_PLUGIN_CACHE** environment variable as follows:

```
export TF_PLUGIN_CACHE=/usr/local/share/terraform/plugins
```

After you set the **TF_PLUGIN_CACHE** variable, re-run terraform init.

Another error message, “No provider config schema available for provider[“terraform.io/builtin/terraform”], indicates that Terraform is not able to locate the provider config schema for the built-in Terraform provider.  It should be noted that there is no error in this regard since the Terraform provider provided with Terraform has no provider config schema.

Here is the example code for a Windows virtual machine with a customer-managed key and key rotation.

**My Demo Terraform configuration:**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.5.6"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.71.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {} #Backend variables are initialized through the secret and variable folders
}

provider "azurerm" {
  #version         = "~> 3.71.0"
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id

  features {}
}
 
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name = "my-key-vault"
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "key" {
  name = "my-key"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  key_type = "RSA"
  key_size = 2048
}

resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "des" {
  name = "my-des"
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  key_encryption_key_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.key.id
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name = "my-vm"
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  vm_size = "Standard_D2s_v3"
  os_disk {
    create_option = "FromImage"
    image_reference {
      publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
      offer = "WindowsServer"
      sku = "2022-Datacenter"
      version = "latest"
    }
    disk_encryption_set_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.des.id
  }
  admin_username = var.admin_username
  admin_password = random_password.password.result
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 12
  special = true
}
```

This code creates an Azure Key Vault and a customer-managed key.  The OS disk of the Windows virtual machine will be encrypted by using the customer-managed key.  Thereupon, the random provider in Terraform is used to generate a password for the VM.

##### `terraform apply -auto-approve`

The new version of CMK was created by Terraform, and the updated disk encryption was set to use the new key version.  A new key will cause a virtual machine to start automatically.